# Finite Covering of Closed Unit Disk?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I'm in an analysis class, and we just learned about the Heine-Borel theorem... But it seems so counterintuitive to me. Even with one of the simplest examples of a closed and bounded set, the closed unit disk, I can't seem to come up with an open cover for it, let alone a finite cover. Could anyone give an example of a finite covering for the closed unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Also, on a separate note, $\mathbb{C}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, right? So does the Heine-Borel theorm imply that every closed and bounded subset of the complex numbers is also compact?

Comment: Yes to your question about $\Bbb C$. Although since we're talking about topologies, you should say "homeomorphic" instead of "isomorphic".

Comment: If one considers the closed unit disk $\bar D$ as a topological space in its own right, with the subspace topology inherited from $\Bbb R^2$, then any cover $\{U_1,U_2,\dots\}$ by sets in $\Bbb R^2$ can be turned into an cover $\{U_1\cap D,U_2\cap D,\dots\}$ by open sets in $\bar D$. I wonder if this is part of your current confusion, because $U_1\cap D$ might not "look open" (and might not be open in $\Bbb R^2$) but is open in $\bar D$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer your questions and make a few points.

1. There are many finite covers of the closed unit disc! Here's one: $\{B_2(0,0)\}$, where $B_2(0,0)$ is the open ball of radius $2$ about the origin $(0,0)$. Here is another: $\{B_2(0,0), B_1(5,0)\}$. Here is another: $\{B_1(1,0), B_1(0,1), B_1(-1,0), B_1(0,-1), B_{1/2}(0,0)\}$. Do you see why these sets of open sets cover the closed unit disc?
2. **However,** the Heine-Borel theorem does not just say there is *some* finite open cover of a closed, bounded set. That would be not very interesting: any set in any topological space has *some* finite open cover; we can just take the cover consisting of only the entire space, $\{X\}$.

   Heine-Borel says that closed and bounded sets are *compact*, which is to say that **for any** open cover there is a finite subcover. It doesn't just say there is some finite cover by open sets that we can make. It says: if you give me any cover by open sets, I can find a finite subcover (*subcover* meaning that I use only the sets you gave me, but I am allowed to use only finitely many of them.)
3. Yes, because $\mathbb{C}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ (*isomorphic* really meaning they are the same except for complex number multiplication, which we don't care about when we are talking about topology), Heine-Borel tells us that any closed and bounded subset of the complex numbers is compact.

Comment: Here's another open cover of the closed unit disk: $$\{B_\varepsilon(q,r)\colon q,r\in\Bbb R\}$$
(for any $\varepsilon>0$ chosen in advance).

Comment: Thanks for the answer 6005! I'm afraid I'm still a little bit confused... For an open cover shouldn't we have $\{U_\alpha\}$ such that $\bar{D}=\bigcup_\alpha U_\alpha$? In your examples I see why $\bar{D}\subset\bigcup_\alpha U_\alpha$, but not why they are equal...

Comment: @analysisstudent An "open cover" of a set $S$ is a collection of open sets whose union *contains* $S$, not a collection whose union is exactly $S$. You are right, in my examples $\overline{D} \subset \bigcup_{\alpha} U_{\alpha}$, but the containment the other way is not true. In fact, a finite union of open sets is open, so if we were not allowed to spill over the edges when covering a set, finite covers could only cover open sets.

Comment: @analysisstudent You're welcome.